# Meteor 1.0 doesn't see bootstrap lib

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

i updated my meteor to 1.0 and created a new project "meteor create myProject", then i ran " mrt add bootstrap-3", it created package directory and added 2 files smart.json and smalt.lock. In my html page i added this code:

```
    <head>
       <title>Meteor Project</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="navbar-inner">
             <div class="container">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
               <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                 <ul class="nav">
                   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
           <h1>Login to continue</h1>
           <p>
             {{> loginButtons}}
           </p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

When i run Meteor it doesn't render this into a navigation bar just bullet points. Also, have troubles with "loginButtons" template, that supposed to come automatically with Meteor but it doesn't, getting error on it too.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have all packages, to do so simply type `meteor list` and your packages should be something like this(plus the ones you added)

```
accounts-base
accounts-facebook
accounts-password
accounts-ui
mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

If they aren't there, delete them using mrt(`mrt delete accounts-ui` for example), and then add them using meteor(as in answer above).

After that `loginButtons` and `bootstrap` should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

Using `mrt` to add packages is deprecated in 1.0 and might not work. The new way to add packages is with `meteor add`. Try this:

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

You should probably delete any files that `mrt` generated in your app, since they are no longer necessary.

Search for packages on [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/).

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick. I assume there is no need anymore for smart.json and smart.lock. Will delete them.